# google calendar api v3 get id of last modified event

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I want to script behavior when people insert event in my calendar.
(e.g. when they add something into my "focus time"). I was able to connect an appscript "trigger" to call `onEventUpdate`. Sadly AppScript does not give you the event id for the event that was modified... (can you confirm the API does not offer this?).

So I tried to fetch the "last updated" events instead:

```
function getOptions() {
  var now = new Date();
  var yesterday = new Date();
  yesterday.setDate(now.getDate() - 1);
  
  console.log(yesterday.toISOString())

  return {
    updateMin: yesterday.toISOString(),
    maxResults: 2,
    orderBy: 'updated',
    singleEvents: true,
    showDeleted: false
  }
}

function onEventUpdate() {
  var options = getOptions();
  var calendarId = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  // var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId);
  // console.log(calendar.getName());

  var events = Calendar.Events.list(calendarId, options);
  if(!events.items) return
  for (var i = 0; i < events.items.length; i++) {
    var event = events.items[i];
    console.log(event.summary + " @ " + event.start['dateTime']);
  }
}
```

Yet, I have just modified an event, but instead I am getting events from the past (i.e. August, 2mo ago...):

```
5:11:21 PM  Notice  Execution started
5:11:21 PM  Info    2022-10-29T00:11:21.826Z
5:11:22 PM  Info    Old Meeting @ 2022-08-08T17:00:00-07:00
5:11:22 PM  Info    Old Meeting @ 2022-08-03T14:00:00-07:00
5:11:22 PM  Notice  Execution completed
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to retrieve the last updated event in a Google Calendar using Google Apps Script.

In the current stage, `orderBy` of "Events: list" can be used with only "ascending". When I saw your script, I thought that the reason for your current issue might be due to this. If "descending" was used with `orderBy`, your script might be able to be used. But, in the current stage, it seems that this cannot be used.

So, in the current stage, in order to retrieve the last updated event, I thought that it is required to retrieve all events with your `getOptions()`, and the last element is required to be retrieved. When this is reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function getOptions() {
  var now = new Date();
  var yesterday = new Date();
  yesterday.setDate(now.getDate() - 1);

  console.log(yesterday.toISOString())

  return {
    updatedMin: yesterday.toISOString(),
    maxResults: 2500, // Modified
    orderBy: 'updated',
    singleEvents: true,
    showDeleted: false
  }
}

function onEventUpdate() {
  var options = getOptions();
  var calendarId = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  
  // I modified the below script.
  var eventList = [];
  var pageToken = null;
  do {
    options.pageToken = pageToken;
    var events = Calendar.Events.list(calendarId, options);
    if (events.items.length > 0) {
      eventList = [...eventList, ...events.items];
    }
    pageToken = events.nextPageToken;
  } while (pageToken);
  var lastUpdatedEvent = eventList.pop(); // You can retrieve the last updated event.
  var lastUpdatedEventId = lastUpdatedEvent.id; // You can retrieve the event ID of the last updated event.
}
```

#### Note:

- About `I was able to connect an appscript "trigger" to call onEventUpdate. Sadly AppScript does not give you the event id for the event that was modified`,  how about reporting this to the Google issue tracker as a future request?

#### Reference:

- [Events: list](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/list)

Comment: @andrea As additional information, if you want to retrieve only the event ID of the last updated event, when `fields: "items(id),nextSyncToken"` is included in `options`, the process cost might be able to be reduced a little.

Comment: Yes, I recalled reading the syncToken logic

Comment: @andrea Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. From your question, I thought that you wanted to retrieve the event of the last updated event. Is my understanding correct? If my understanding was not correct, can you provide the detail of your actual goal? Because when I tested my proposed script, the last updated event is returned. If my understanding is not correct, I have to apologize.

Comment: @andrea There's a small typo in both your question and this answer. The parameter `updateMin` should be `updatedMin` instead, so the filter is not getting through and you are getting old events instead. When you make these changes, you should be able to retrieve only recent events.

Comment: @Iamblichus Thank you for your comment. I couldn't notice the query parameter of `updateMin`. Thank you for your always support.

Comment: Argh, you are right, then it's a "different" bug – mine.
They ought to verify the option schema though...

Comment: @andrea Thank you for replying. I used `pageToken` because I'm not sure about your actual situation from your question. I think that this is due to my poor English skill. I have to apologize for this. But, from your posted answer, it seems that the logic that the last update event is the last element of the event list retrieved from `Calendar.Events.list` was useful. I'm glad about it. I deeply apologize that I couldn't imagine your actual situation from your question, again.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I achieved what I wanted to (thanks for spotting my typo). I take some risk, as I assume there is no more than 50 edited events in the last hour (although risk could be reduced by making this delta smaller).

This is what the overly-convoluted way appscript needs (i.e. they could have just given me a calendar-event object as an argument to the trigger? oh well)

This is just a simple example, as now I can programmatically edit my calendar at will :)

```
function getOptions() {
  var now = new Date();
  TIME_DIFF = 60 * 60 * 1000;
  var earlier = new Date(now.getTime() - TIME_DIFF)
  return {
    updatedMin: earlier.toISOString(),
    maxResults: 50,
    orderBy: 'updated',
    singleEvents: true,
    showDeleted: false
  }
}

function getLastEditedEvent() {
  // returns https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-event
  var options = getOptions();
  var calendarId = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  var events = Calendar.Events.list(calendarId, options);
  if(!events.items) return undefined;
  var _event = events.items[events.items.length-1];
  return CalendarApp.getEventById(_event.id);
}

function onEventUpdate() {
  // sadly event update contains no information
  var event = getLastEditedEvent()
  if(event == undefined) return;
  console.log('Modifying: ' + event.getTitle() + ' @ ' + event.getStartTime());
  event.setColor(CalendarApp.EventColor.PALE_BLUE);
}
```